# To make a ObservableCollection working with the results of an Linq expression

Tags: c#, linq, sql-order-by, observablecollection

How to make a ObservableCollection working with the results of an Linq expression?

Ex:

```
items = new ObservableCollection<Item>(ctx.Items.Local.OrderBy(i => i.Name));
items.Add(new Item { Name = "ITEM NAME" });
```

At the time of saving the context, the above code does not work because:

```
var a items.Count; //a is 1
var b ctx.Items.Local.Count; //b is 0 --> Nothing added!!
```

Why A not equals B?? Can anyone help?

**Obs. ctx is a DBContext**

Comment: ctx.items implies this is a db context is that correct? if not, what is ctx?

Comment: @JohnPeters , ctx.items is a db context

Comment: What happens when you use ctx.items.Save();

Comment: I think the issue is that the observablecollection is not known to EF, rather it knows about a List<Item> ...

Comment: @JohnPeters , ctx.SaveChanges() not save the item added. Why?

Comment: try ctx.items.add(xyz), then save it.

Comment: items and ctx.items are not the same thing.

Comment: @JohnPeters , i do not agree because if you remove the OrderBy works

Comment: You are right, try this var temp = ctx.Items.Local.OrderBy(i => i.Name), what do you see?

Comment: temp = ctx.Items.Local.OrderBy(i => i.Name) same problem

Comment: I thought an observablecollection serve for this purpose

Comment: No the observable collection is for WPF or UWP.  The data base doesn't store lists of observablecollections it stores colllections of items or item.

Comment: `Local` is already `ObservableCollection`, you should return it as is if you want to be able to reflect the modifications. Once you apply any LINQ operator, the connection to the original `ObservableCollection` is lost. This is the so called `Model`. Filtering and ordering should be done in the `View`s using that `Model`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you are hoping to happen. a being 1 and b being 0 is what I would expect from the code you have shared.

Check ObservableCollection's source code in http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/compmod/system/collections/objectmodel/observablecollection.cs

The constructor you are using will copy the contents of the list, so any further changes in items will not be reflected in the list used in its constructor, or in this case the IEnumerable.

```
public ObservableCollection(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    if (collection == null)
        throw new ArgumentNullException("collection");
    CopyFrom(collection);
}

private void CopyFrom(IEnumerable<T> collection)
{
    IList<T> items = Items;
    if (collection != null && items != null)
    {
        using (IEnumerator<T> enumerator = collection.GetEnumerator())
        {
            while (enumerator.MoveNext())
            {
                items.Add(enumerator.Current);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If you want to listen to items changes, and reflect the changes in the base list, perhaps you can do this in `items.CollectionChanged`